# I want to write custom xsl for ditamaps in DITA

Tags: xslt-1.0, dita

I want to write custom xsl for DITA. I have three Dita maps like `book.ditamap` and `chapter1.ditamap`, `chapter2.ditamap`, I want fetch  just titles which I gave in this ditamaps.

My `book.ditamap` looks like this:

```
<bookmap id="pdfnntd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:dita:xsd:bookmap.xsd">

  <booktitle>
    <booklibrary>Books about stuff</booklibrary>
    <mainbooktitle>A book about one thing</mainbooktitle>
  </booktitle>

  <chapter href="chapter1.ditamap" format="ditamap"/>
  <chapter href="chapter2.ditamap" format="ditamap"/>
</bookmap>
```

My `chapter1.ditamap`looks like this:

```
<map id="pdfnnt" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLenter code hereocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:dita:xsd:map.xsd">

  <topichead>
    <topicmeta>
      <navtitle>Threads</navtitle>
    </topicmeta>
    <topicref href="task/lesson1.xml" type="task"></topicref>
    <topicref href="task/lesson2.xml" type="task"></topicref>
  </topichead>
 </map>
```

For these ditamaps I want to write custom xsl in DITA. I searched in your website, I tried one example but DITA is taking default xsl only. Please help me out in this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've edited your question to make it more readable and added tag `dita` since I assume that you will require help from DITA specialists to make your system find the right XSLT sheet. When this is solved and you start writing your actual XSLT we will need your desired output XML and your XSLT to help you further along the way in XSLT coding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're looking to create this for a PDF transform. I recommend getting a copy of either DITA for Practitioners or DITA for Print. What you need to do is create a plugin to override the base XSL and extract using XPATH to grab both mainbooktitle and topicmeta/title (the exact xpath is more complex than what I've written here).

You haven't specified precisely what you want to do with the titles, so it's difficult to come up with a meaningful example.

HTH.

Comment: i want this for xhtml.I want to fetch titles alone and display in xhtml from.I wrote custom xsl but it is not working  here is my custom xsl

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="1.0">
  <xsl:output  name="html" method="html" indent="yes" />
 
   <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>
   <xsl:value-of select="bookmap/booktitle/mainbooktitle"/></title></head>
   <body>
   
   </body>
   </html>
  <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="chapter"/>-->
    </xsl:template>

Comment: How did you package this? You need a plugin that extends the xhtml transform to pick up this code. The plugin should be a unique transtype.

More information will be useful to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The DITA for Publishers project (dita4publishers.sourceforge.net) provides a general XSLT map-processing framework that you can use to do convenient processing on maps, including getting the effective navigation titles for topic refs. The D4P distribution includes a sample plugin, net.sourceforge.dita4publishers.graphviz/, that demonstrates how to use the code in the context of a relatively simple process (generating Graphviz diagrams for the navigation tree or back-of-the-book index of DITA maps).

Be sure to download the latest 0.9.19 release candidate, not the 0.9.18 package--I'm behind in getting an official release 0.9.19 together with updated documentation and so on, but the 0.9.19 code has many bug fixes that you will want.

Cheers,

Eliot